# waste "new line symbol" in variable in expect script

Tags: expect

expect write to variable text with waste "new line symbol" from output line

how to solve this problem?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/expect -f

set timeout 30
puts "enter the path to output folder"
while 1 { 
expect {
    "*\n" {
        set outdir $expect_out(buffer)
       break
    } timeout {
        puts "warning: timed out"
        set outdir $DEFAULT_OUT
        break
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set outdir [string trim $expect_out(buffer)]
```

Also, check the [expect man page](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/expect1.html), there are a few examples of user entry:

```
 stty -echo
 send_user "Password: "
 expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
 set password $expect_out(1,string)
 stty echo
```